# Notifications macOS with Go

Tags: linux, macos, go, push-notification

I made a simple app that sends notifications in Go. In Linux, using `notify-send` everything works well, while in macOS `osascript` sends notifications without the icon (it uses the default AppleScript icon), and I need my icon to be displayed. I also don't want to use `terminal-notifier`, since not everyone has it.

How can I send notifications with Go in macOS displaying the icon (with `osascript` or even with some other external library)?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/gen2brain/beeep or https://github.com/keybase/go-notifier ? (Never used them, I’ve just google for "golang MacOS notification")

Comment: the first one uses osascript. The second one I don't know how to use it. It could be the correct one but I don't know how to use it. Could you explain? I'm still learning Go.
I only need to use Title, subtitle and icon, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an icon to a notification through osascript, as you can see from the documentation: [display notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224)

> Posts a notification using the Notification Center, containing a title, subtitle, and explanation, and optionally playing a sound.

You can find some clarification also in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49079025/5199939

Comment: And is there another tool to send notifications that support the icon?

Comment: A possible alternative could be to use something like growl: [http://growl.info/downloads](http://growl.info/downloads).

Comment: Yes but something that doesn’t need to be downloaded

Comment: The only remaining options are: using a dialog: [display dialog](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW12); or saving the script as an app and change the `.icns` icon file

Comment: How can I use it in go?